# Composer shows me trace info

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, composer-php

I have created a stack to develop with symfony and docker (to learn more about docker) but when I run composer, it shows me debug information.

I have tried with several dockerfiles, using composer's own image or doing as indicated in the documentation on the main website

- dockerfile 1:

```
    #FROM composer:2.6.6 as composer
FROM php:8.3-fpm-alpine AS base

# Install dependencies ALPINE
RUN apk add --no-cache mysql-client msmtp perl wget procps git shadow libzip libpng libjpeg-turbo libwebp freetype icu icu-data-full

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-essentials \
    icu-dev icu-libs zlib-dev g++ make automake autoconf libzip-dev \
    libpng-dev libwebp-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev freetype-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-webp && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd && \
    docker-php-ext-install mysqli && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && \
    docker-php-ext-install intl && \
    docker-php-ext-install opcache && \
    docker-php-ext-install exif && \
    docker-php-ext-install zip && \
    apk del build-essentials && rm -rf /usr/src/php*

# Install composer
#COPY --from=composer /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# PHP Extensions
#RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql opcache zip intl

RUN wget https://getcomposer.org/composer-stable.phar -O /usr/local/bin/composer && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer

# Symfony CLI
ARG SYMFONY_CLI_VERSION
RUN wget https://github.com/symfony-cli/symfony-cli/releases/download/v$SYMFONY_CLI_VERSION/symfony-cli_linux_amd64.tar.gz \
 && tar -xvzf symfony-cli_linux_amd64.tar.gz \
 && chmod +x symfony \
 && mv symfony /usr/local/bin/

# Usuario
ARG USER_NAME
ARG GROUP
ARG UID
#ARG GID

#RUN addgroup --gid $GID $GROUP
RUN adduser --disabled-password --gecos "" --uid $UID  $USER_NAME


# Cleanup
RUN rm -rf /usr/src/* \
 && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /var/www/html
USER $USER_NAME
```

- dockerfile 2:

```
FROM php:8.3-fpm-alpine
RUN apk add --no-cache mysql-client msmtp perl wget procps shadow libzip libpng libjpeg-turbo libwebp freetype icu icu-data-full

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual build-essentials \
    icu-dev icu-libs zlib-dev g++ make automake autoconf libzip-dev \
    libpng-dev libwebp-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev freetype-dev && \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg --with-webp && \
    docker-php-ext-install gd && \
    docker-php-ext-install mysqli && \
    docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql && \
    docker-php-ext-install intl && \
    docker-php-ext-install opcache && \
    docker-php-ext-install exif && \
    docker-php-ext-install zip && \
    apk del build-essentials && rm -rf /usr/src/php*

RUN wget https://getcomposer.org/composer-stable.phar -O /usr/local/bin/composer && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/composer
```

and when i run composer -v:

```
.L36:
        mov 0x50(%r14), %rdi
        sub $0x1, (%rdi)
        jnz .L37
        call zend_array_destroy
        jmp .L21
.L37:
        test $0xfffffc10, 0x4(%rdi)
        jnz .L21
        call gc_possible_root
        jmp .L21
.L38:
        test $0x1, 0x69(%r14)
        jz .L23
        mov 0x60(%r14), %rdi
        sub $0x1, (%rdi)
        jnz .L23
        call _efree
        jmp .L23
.L39:
        mov 0x50(%r14), %rdi
        sub $0x1, (%rdi)
        jnz .L24
        call _efree
        jmp .L24

  self-update          [selfupdate] Updates composer.phar to the latest version
  show                 [info] Shows information about packages
  status               Shows a list of locally modified packages
  suggests             Shows package suggestions
  update               [u|upgrade] Updates your dependencies to the latest version according to composer.json, and updates the composer.lock file
  validate             Validates a composer.json and composer.lockTRACE-83$Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatterStyle::apply$95: ; (unknown)
        mov $EG(jit_trace_num), %rax
        mov $0x53, (%rax)
        cmp $0x1, 0x2c(%r14)
        jb jit$$trace_exit_0
        cmp $0x6, 0x58(%r14)
        jnz .L7
.L1:
        mov 0x20(%r14), %rdi
        mov 0x80(%rdi), %edx
        test %dl, %dl
        jz jit$$trace_exit_1
        mov 0x78(%rdi), %rcx
        test %dh, %dh
        jz .L3
        cmp $0xa, %dl
        jnz .L2
        mov 0x10(%rcx), %edx
        mov 0x8(%rcx), %rcx
        test %dh, %dh
        jz .L3
.L2:
        add $0x1, (%rcx)
.L3:
        mov %rcx, 0x70(%r14)
        mov %edx, 0x78(%r14)
        test $0x1, 0x79(%r14)
        jnz .L8
.L4:
        mov 0x78(%r14), %cl
        cmp $0x1, %cl
        jz jit$$trace_exit_2
        mov 0x20(%r14), %rdi
        cmp $0x1, 0x70(%rdi)
        jnz jit$$trace_exit_3
        mov $0x1, 0x78(%r14)
        mov 0x20(%r14), %rdi
        mov 0x30(%rdi), %edx
        cmp $0x8, %dl
        jnz jit$$trace_exit_5
        mov 0x28(%rdi), %rcx
        mov %rcx, 0x60(%r14)
        mov %edx, 0x68(%r14)
        add $0x1, (%rcx)
        mov 0x60(%r14), %rdi
        mov %rdi, (%rsp)
        mov 0x40(%r14), %rax
        mov 0x58(%rax), %rdx
        cmp 0x10(%rdi), %rdx
        jnz .L9
        mov 0x60(%rax), %rax
.L5:
        mov $0x55e7948b2478, %rcx
        cmp %rcx, %rax
        jnz jit$$trace_exit_6
        mov $EG(vm_stack_top), %r15
        mov (%r15), %r15
        mov $EG(vm_stack_end), %rdx
        mov (%rdx), %rdx
        sub %r15, %rdx
        cmp $0x90, %rdx
        jb jit$$trace_exit_7
        mov $EG(vm_stack_top), %rdx
        add $0x90, (%rdx)
        mov %rax, 0x18(%r15)
        mov (%rsp), %rcx
        mov %rcx, 0x20(%r15)
        mov $0x200308, 0x28(%r15)
        mov $0x1, 0x2c(%r15)
        mov 0x50(%r14), %rdx
        mov %rdx, 0x50(%r15)
        mov 0x58(%r14), %eax
        mov %eax, 0x58(%r15)
        test %ah, %ah
        jz .L6
        add $0x1, (%rdx)
.L6:
        mov $0x55e7948ada38, %rax
        mov %rax, (%r14)
        mov %r14, 0x30(%r15)
        mov $0x0, 0x8(%r15)
        lea 0x60(%r14), %rdx
        mov %rdx, 0x10(%r15)
        mov $CG(map_ptr_base), %rcx
        mov (%rcx), %rdx
        mov 0x8049(%rdx), %rdx
        mov %rdx, 0x40(%r15)
        mov $EG(current_execute_data), %rcx
        mov %r15, (%rcx)
        mov %r15, %r14
        mov $0x55e7948b25a8, %r15
        jmp TRACE-82$Symfony\Component\Console\Color::apply$70
.L7:
        lea 0x50(%r14), %rdi
        mov %r15, (%r14)
        mov $0x55e7948ada78, %rsi
        mov $zend_jit_verify_arg_slow, %rax
        call *%rax
        test %al, %al
        jnz .L1
        jmp JIT$$exception_handler
.L8:
        mov 0x70(%r14), %rdi
        sub $0x1, (%rdi)
        jmp .L4
.L9:
        mov $0x55e7948ad518, %rsi
        lea (%rsp), %rdx
        mov $0x55e7948ad9f8, %rax
        mov %rax, (%r14)
        mov $zend_jit_find_method_tmp_helper, %rax
        call *%rax
        test %rax, %rax
        jnz .L5
        jmp JIT$$exception_handler
```

why does this happen? How can I prevent it?

thanks

UPDATE:
thanks @Sitethief,

that command was an example, if i do composer without arguments:

```
.L34:
        mov 0x80(%r14), %rdi
        sub $0x1, (%rdi)
        jmp .L14
.L35:
        mov 0x80(%r14), %rdi
        sub $0x1, (%rdi)
        jmp .L16
.L36:
        mov 0x50(%r14), %rdi
        sub $0x1, (%rdi)
        jnz .L37
        call zend_array_destroy
        jmp .L21
.L37:
        test $0xfffffc10, 0x4(%rdi)
        jnz .L21
        call gc_possible_root
        jmp .L21
.L38:
        test $0x1, 0x69(%r14)
        jz .L23
        mov 0x60(%r14), %rdi
        sub $0x1, (%rdi)
        jnz .L23
        call _efree
        jmp .L23
.L39:
        mov 0x50(%r14), %rdi
        sub $0x1, (%rdi)
        jnz .L24
        call _efree
        jmp .L24

  show                 [info] Shows information about packages
  status               Shows a list of locally modified packages
  suggests             Shows package suggestions
  update               [u|upgrade] Updates your dependencies to the latest version according to composer.json, and updates the composer.lock file
  validate             Validates a composer.json and composer.lock
```

EDIT2: if i dont install opcache, composer goes right without TRACE output.

what is wrong here?

Comment: Looks like somewhere in your source code is assembly language and composer (or whatever else in your pipeline) cannot process it.

Comment: its a clear image...i have not source code